# Decorating standard components in composite components, how to inherit attributes?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I am wondering if there is a nice way to decorate components with composite components?

Example:

```
<composite:implementation>
    <div style="someFancyClass">
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" />
    </div>
</composite:implementation>
```

In this case the value attribute is passed through to the contained `<h:inputText>`. But what about all the other attributes? Do I have to declare all of them in the `<composite:interface>` section?

It would be nice to have some kind of inheritance from standard components, so that e.g. the maxlength attribute of `<h:inputText>` is automatically available at the composite component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Do I have to declare all of them in the `<composite:interface>` section?*

Not necessary, you can just use `maxlength="#{cc.attrs.maxlength}"` without the need to declare it as `<composite:attribute>`. However, this is bad for documentatory purposes. The developer would not see this attribute to appear in the composite component's documentation (which might be used by IDE autocompletion, for example).

---

> *It would be nice to have some kind of inheritance from standard components, so that e.g. the maxlength attribute of `<h:inputText>` is automatically available at the composite component.*

That's not possible. For that you'd really need to create a fullworthy custom `UIInput` component and/or a `Renderer` (in your particular case, just the renderer ought to be sufficient).

Comment: Thx for the answer, you are right, a renderer would be appropriate in the simple case shown above. But if I had to do it in the backing class, I could just copy the elements from attributes map to the attributes of the nested <h:inputText>, right? Which method would be right for that? decode() or should the component respond to the postAddToViewEvent? I'm just curious about it.

Answer (score 0):

I provided an example on how to decorate a composite component here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8881510/1151983

However, this does not provide real inheritance, but a way to share common stuff between a set of similar composite components.