# Comparing entities with EL equality operator does not ever seem to return true

Tags: list, jsf, el, equality

I'm iterating over a list of entities, rendering some links with specific icons. I'd like to conditionally set a `class` attribute value during the iteration based on the currently active lesson as below, so that the "active" item gets a different style:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{lessonBean.allLessons}" var="lesson">
    <li>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandLink>
                <i class="#{lessonBean.currentLesson == lesson ? 'green' : ''}" />
            </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
    </li>                                        
</ui:repeat>
```

It only doesn't seem to ever return `true` on the comparison and thus `green` is never printed. I've searched for examples and found [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094429/highlighting-selected-menu/) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473461/twitter-bootstrap-jsf-2-active-menu-style/) using `#{view.viewId}`, but this doesn't suit my requirement.

How can I achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

This construct will fail if the `Lesson` entity doesn't have the [`Object#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method properly implemented and thus two instances representing the same "value" will never be equal.

Act accordingly. Here's an example based on entity's technical ID:

```
private Long id;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other != null && getClass() == other.getClass() && id != null)
        ? id.equals(getClass().cast(other).id)
        : (other == this);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Right way to implement equals contract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181339/right-way-to-implement-equals-contract/3181374#3181374)

Comment: i've tried this '#{lessonBean.lsn.id == lesson.id ? 'green' : ''}'
and still not getting true

Comment: So those don't return the expected values?

Comment: Well, then make sure that they return the expected values, so that the comparision will return `true`.